# Запрос всех значений полей MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Имеется таблица *product* с большим количеством полей.

Нужно выбрать у каждого поля все значения (удалить дублирующие) и составить `JSON`.

Первое что приходит в голову, это отправлять 1 запрос к 1 полю, результат сохранять в переменную, и так пока поля не закончатся. Думаю это не правильно, слишком много запросов.

Как можно сделать это 1 запросом и вообще можно так?

Comment: Возможно вам [это](http://oracleplsql.ru/distinct.html) поможет.

Comment: @Rootware спасибо, но если мы будем применять эту команду к нескольким столбцам, значения в каждом столбце будут дублироваться, разве нет?

Comment: читайте просто всю таблицу целиком и каждое поле раскладывайте в ассоциативный массив, а потом его ключи, разложите в json.